# Load csv file again during gatling simulation

Tags: csv, gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to run a simulation with two scenarios.
The setUp looks like this

```scala
setUp(
 scn1.inject(rampConcurrentUsers(minUserCount) to (tps) during (testRampSeconds seconds),constantConcurrentUsers(tps) during (testDurationSeconds seconds)).throttle(reachRps(tps) in (1 seconds), holdFor(testDurationSeconds seconds), jumpToRps(0), holdFor(60 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
 scn2.inject(nothingFor(testDurationSeconds),atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol)
  )
```

Scenario 1 makes REST API calls and the response data is saved in a csv file

PrintWriter to write to file:

```scala
  val fileWriter = {
    val fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("foo.csv")
    val appTokenWriter = new java.io.PrintWriter(fos,true)
    appTokenWriter.println("data")
    appTokenWriter
  }
```

Scenario 2 waits for Scenario 1 to complete so that it can process all entries in the csv file at once.

```scala
.foreach(csv(foo.csv).readRecords,"record") {
      exec(flattenMapIntoAttributes("${record}"))
      .exec(session => {
        println(session("data").as[String])
        session
      })
      .exec(...REST Call...)
```

The csv(foo.csv).readRecord is not picking up the values that were flushed by scenario1 into the csv.
csv(foo.csv).readRecords.size = 0 in Scenario2 but I can see the data written in the file

Is this the right way to maintain data between two scenarios?
If yes, how do I make the .readRecords API pick the latest changes.
If no, please suggest the right way to do this.

Edit: Based on Stephane's implementation, tried using ConcurrentLinkedDeque

```scala
package com.intuit.platform.identity.oauth2.performance.simulation

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.feeder.Feeder
import io.gatling.http.Predef.http

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

/**
 * @author vnarayanan
 */
class SOSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http.baseUrl("localhost:8080")

  val dataQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque[String]()

  val saveInQueue = exec{ session => {
    dataQueue.offer(session("data").as[String])
    session
  }
  }

  class DataFeeder extends Feeder[String] {
    override def hasNext: Boolean = dataQueue.size() > 0
    override def next(): Map[String, String] = {
      Map("data" ->dataQueue.poll())
    }
  }
  
  val scenario1  = scenario("Scenario1")
    .exec(session => {
      session.set("data", Random.alphanumeric.take(20).mkString)
    })
    .exec(saveInQueue)

//I need to stop the requests when the queue is empty. tried it with two solutions:
//  1) asLongAs
//  2) repeat (commented)


  val scenario2  = scenario("Scenario2")
    .exec(session => {
      println(dataQueue.size())
      session
    })
    .asLongAs(dataQueue.size() > 0) {
      exec(session => {
        println(dataQueue.size())
        session
      })
        .feed(new DataFeeder())
        .exec(session => {
          println(session("data").as[String])
          session
        })
    }

//  With Repeat

//  val scenario2  = scenario("Scenario2")
//    .exec(session => {
//      println(dataQueue.size())
//      session
//    })
//    .repeat(dataQueue.size() ) {
//      exec(session => {
//        println(dataQueue.size())
//        session
//      })
//        .feed(new DataFeeder())
//        .exec(session => {
//          println(session("data").as[String])
//          session
//        })
//    }
    

  setUp(
    scenario1.inject(atOnceUsers(10)).throttle(reachRps(1) in (1 seconds), holdFor(5 seconds), jumpToRps(0), holdFor(10 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
    scenario2.inject(nothingFor(5 seconds),atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol)

  ).maxDuration(10 seconds)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with our built in csv feeders.
Now, remember that `Feeder` is an alias for `Iterator[Map[String, Any]]`, so you can write your own implementation that would support your use case.
For example, instead of writing to and reading from a file, you could keep the data in memory in a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try with ConcurrentLinkedDeque. `val appTokensToDeleteQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue[String]()  class DataFeeder extends Feeder[String] {
    override def hasNext: Boolean = AppTokensToDeleteQueueHolder.appTokensToDeleteQueue.size() > 0
    override def next(): Map[String, String] = {
      println(AppTokensToDeleteQueueHolder.appTokensToDeleteQueue.size())
      Map("appToken" -> AppTokensToDeleteQueueHolder.appTokensToDeleteQueue.poll())
    }
  }
` and initialized .feed(new DataFeeder()). For this, queue is always empty. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You have to offer data into the queue in scenario1.

Comment: Yes, this is how we offer content to the Deque `AppTokensToDeleteQueueHolder.appTokensToDeleteQueue.offer(session("appToken").as[String])` I was wrong in the previous comment. The queue is not empty but the DataFeeder in the .feed call is not doing anything. Is the initialization and code for the DataFeeder done right?

Comment: It should work. Please provide a a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (see http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Added an edit in the question with the example code.

Comment: That's always the same mistake: you're passing the value as it is when the Simulation is instantiated instead of passing a function that will be evaluated at runtime and will see the updated value. `asLongAs(session => !dataQueue.isEmpty)`